# Change Apache Virtual Host port and a strange thing happened

Tags: wordpress, apache

I'm using Ubuntu with Apache 2.4.  and I have **2 domain names** point to this server.

Previous I have a virtual host (a Wordpress site) running on port 8444, and it **worked fine**, I can access it via http://abcdef.com:8444.

Now I want switching it to Port 80 by just 2 lines change:

from:

```
Listen 8444
<VirtualHost *:8444>
    ServerName abcdef.com
    ServerAlias www.abcdef.con
    ......
    ......
</VirtualHost>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abcdef.com
    ServerAlias www.abcdef.con
    ......
    ......
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart Apache service.
**(NOTE, I have no change to ports.conf)**

I think this is all done, but when I accessing this site by http://abcdef.com, Http Response code 301 always returned, and Browser always redirect me to abcdef.com:8444, and of course a none page is shown.

This is really strange for me, even I've tried

- `apt-get purge apache2`, and reinstall apache again.
- `a2dissite` for the second site, and make sure only this site is running on Apache.

  still the same behavior, every place of 8444 should be delete from Apache, how this redirect from?

Comment: This could be a WP issue, check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155471/when-moving-a-wp-site-why-does-wp-admin-redirect-to-old-site)

Comment: Better yet: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/13778/37905

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you changed the line

```
Listen 8444
```

to:

```
Listen 80
```

as well, right?

Can you post the contents your .htaccess file? HTTP code 301 means a permanent redirection, it might be you Rewrite Rules that are doing this.